# Combining the results of nested `tar_map` calls

Tags: r, target, targets-r-package

I am creating a pipeline that allows for an arbitrary number of dataset names to be put in, where they will all be put through similar cleaning processes. To do this, I am using the `targets` package, and using the `tar_map` function from `tarchetypes`, I subject each dataset to a series of tidying and wrangling functions.

My issue now is that one dataset needs to be split into three datasets by a factor (a la `split`) while the rest should remain untouched. The pipeline would then theoretically move on by processing each dataset individually, including the three 'daughter' datasets.

Here's my best attempt:

```
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)
library(tidyverse)

# dir.create("./data")
# tibble(nums = 1:300, groups = rep(letters[1:3], each = 100)) |> 
#   write_csv("./data/td1.csv")
# tibble(nums = 301:600, groups = rep(letters[1:3], each = 100)) |> 
#   write_csv("./data/td2.csv")
# tibble(nums = 601:900, groups = rep(letters[1:3], each = 100)) |> 
#   write_csv("./data/td3.csv")

tar_option_set(
  packages = c("tidyverse")
)

read_data <- function(paths) {
  read_csv(paths)
}

get_group <- function(data, groups) {
  filter(data, groups == groups)
}

do_nothing <- function(data) {
  data
}

list(
  map1 <- tar_map(
    values = tibble(datasets = c("./data/td1.csv", "./data/td2.csv", "./data/td3.csv")),
    tar_target(data, read_data(datasets)),
    map2 <- tar_map(values = tibble(groups = c("a", "b", "c")),
            tar_skip(tester, get_group(data, groups), !str_detect(tar_name(), "td3\\.csv$"))
    ),
    tar_target(dn, do_nothing(list(data, tester)))
  )
)
```

The skipping method is a bit clumsy, I may be thinking about that wrong as well.

I'm obviously trying to combine the code poorly at the end there by putting them in a list, but I'm at a loss as to what else to do.

The datasets can't be combined by, say, `rbind`, since in actuality they are `SummarizedExperiment` objects.

Any help is appreciated - let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the levels of that factor in advance, you can handle the splitting of that third dataset with a separate `tar_map()` call similar to what you do now. If you do not know the factor levels in advance, then the splitting needs to be handled with dynamic branching, and I recommend something like `tarchetypes::tar_group_by()`.

I do not think `tar_skip()` is relevant here, and I recommend removing it.

If you start with physical files (or write physical files) then I strongly suggest you track them with `format = "file"`: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/files.html#external-input-files.

```r
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)
tar_option_set(packages = "tidyverse")

list(
  tar_map(
    values = list(paths = c("data/td1.csv", "data/td2.csv")),
    tar_target(file, paths, format = "file"),
    tar_target(data, read_csv(file, col_types = cols()))
  ),
  tar_target(file3, "data/td3.csv", format = "file"),
  tar_group_by(data3, read_csv(file3, col_types = cols()), groups),
  tar_target(
    data3_row_counts,
    tibble(group = data3$groups[1], n = nrow(data3)),
    pattern = map(data3)
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Landau. The lab decided to go with a different analysis strategy for the time being, so I have yet to implement your solution - but I imagine I will be returning to it in time.